# Dispatch action midstream

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

New to RxJS. And redux-observable.

I am having trouble I am trying to dispatch an action midstream `of(takeAction())` in code below,  then listen to responding actions from this, either a `RESOLVE_TAKE` type or `REJECT_TAKE` type. However my `of(takeAction)` is not triggering, would anyone know how to fix this code below?

As an aside from this question, a bonus: Any style advice on how to restructure my code, I'm not sure if its the cleanest most readable way. I am doing a fetch, then a `switch` on the different status codes, then to get `res` (response of fetch) and `reply`, and turn reply to json if possible, and then pass `res` and `reply` both as arguments to `takeAction`. Then wait for the `takeAction` pipeline to dispatch either a `RESOLVE_TAKE` or `REJECT_TAKE`.

```
action$.pipe(
    ofType(START_FOO),
    switchMap({ url } =>
        from(fetch(url)).pipe(
            mergeMap(res => from(res.text()).pipe(
                mergeMap(reply => {
                    try { reply = JSON.parse(reply) } catch(ignore) {}
                    switch (res.status) {
                        case 200: {
                            return of(takeAction(res, reply)).pipe( // not dispatching
                                action$.pipe(
                                    ofType(RESOLVE_TAKE, REJECT_TAKE),
                                    mergeMap(({ type }) => {
                                        if (type === RESOLVE_TAKE) {
                                            return of(resolveFooAction())
                                        } else {
                                            return of(rejectFooAction())
                                        }
                                    })
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        // other res.status cases go here
                    }
                })
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with your `of(takeAction(res, reply))`. Specifically, it's the `.pipe(...)`. That's sending your "takeAction" command to the stuff *inside* the `.pipe` as opposed to letting it "flow" out to your Redux store. Maybe something like the following will work better:

```js
action$.pipe(
  ofType(START_FOO),
  switchMap({ url } =>
    from(fetch(url)).pipe(
      mergeMap(res => from(res.text()).pipe(
        mergeMap(reply => {
          try {
            reply = JSON.parse(reply)
          } catch (ignore) {
          }

          switch (res.status) {
            case 200: {
              return merge(
                of(takeAction(res, reply)),
                action$.pipe(
                  ofType(RESOLVE_TAKE, REJECT_TAKE),
                  map(({ type }) => {
                    if (type === RESOLVE_TAKE) {
                      return resolveFooAction()
                    } else {
                      return rejectFooAction()
                    }
                  }),
                ),
              )
            }
            // other res.status cases go here
          }
        })
      )
    )
  )
)
```

In the above, the `of(takeAction(res, reply))` is *not* piped into anything. Instead, it's being "flowed" back out to the Redux store. The `merge` is one way to flow something out while, at the same time, creating another subscription to the action stream to temporarily listen for another event.

Comment: Oh wow "sending your "takeAction" command to the stuff inside the .pipe" this I think just made something click, thank you very much for this solution! Also I see you kept similar style guide to mine, which makes me feel "YES! i think I'm doing things right rxjs!" Thanks! :)

Comment: How would things differe if instead of doing a `merge` around it, we did a `concat`? Does `merge` make the two things happen in paralell?

Comment: @Noitidart Yes, parallel vs sequential. I'll admit, I was being lazy picking merge over concat and not researching any possible race condition that may exist subscribing to the inner observables. I'll try to add a code test later to confirm and make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks very much!!